# Real time stdout redirect from a python function call to an async method

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, stdout, justpy

So I have a heavy time-consuming function call `my_heavy_function` and I need to redirect that output to a web interface that is calling it, I have a method to send messages to the web interface, let's called that method `async push_message_to_user()`.

basically, it's something like

```
import time 

def my_heavy_function():
    time_on = 0 
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f'time spend {time_on}')
        time_on = time_on+1

async def push_message_to_user(message:str):
    # some lib implementation 
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_heavy_function() # how push prints to the UI ?
```

maybe there is a way giving `my_heavy_function(stdout_obj)`  and use that "std_object"(StringIO) to do something like `stdout_object.push(f'time spend {time_on}')`. I can do that, but what I can't change the `my_heavy_function()` by an async version, to add `push_message_to_user()` directly instead of the `print` (it's used by other non-ascyn routines)

what I would want it's something like (pseudocode)

```
with contextlib.redirect_output(my_prints):
    my_heavy_function()
    while my_prints.readable():
        # realtime push
        await push_message_to_user(my_prints)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus/), a mixed sync-async queue.

Comment: @HTF I've just tried janus, and worked, but only with the same read/loop is there an example with an indeterminate number of messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comment of `@HTF` I finally managed to solve the problem with [janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus/). I copy the example of the repo, and I modified in order to receive a variable number of messages (because I don't know how many iterations `my_heavy_function()` will use)

```
import asyncio
import janus
import time 

def my_heavy_function(sync_q):
    for i in range(10):
        sync_q.put(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    sync_q.put('end')    # is there a more elegant way to do this ?
    sync_q.join()


async def async_coro(async_q):
    while True:
        val = await async_q.get()
        print(f'arrived {val}')
        # send val to UI 
        # await push_message_to_user(val)
        async_q.task_done()
        if val == 'end': 
            break

async def main():
    queue = janus.Queue()
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    fut = loop.run_in_executor(None, my_heavy_function, queue.sync_q)
    await async_coro(queue.async_q)
    await fut
    queue.close()
    await queue.wait_closed()


asyncio.run(main())
```